# Lua, threads and C++ exceptions

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua, exception-safety

I'm planning on suggesting to my development team that we start looking at lua instead of C++ for the project we're currently working on. On that subject I have a question that I need to clear up first.

With the current SDK, we are not allowed to use C++ exceptions due to it not being safe in multithreaded applications (created with that SDK). Actually, it is allowed, just discouraged... however the program won't compile unless we pass -fno-exceptions, so... yeah...

Anyway. Since Lua runs in it's own VM and is pure C... Would exceptions in Lua be 'safe'?

Comment: Maybe you missed a tag... what SDK are you talking about?

Comment: It's a proprietary SDK that we use on the embedded devices we work with.

Comment: FYI: Lua is *also* not thread-safe. So if you're giving up exceptions due to not being thread-safe, I don't see how this helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the C code that makes up the LUA interpreter is fine concerning the restrictions of your SDK then anything coded in LUA and executed with that interpreter is fine, too. But if the LUA interpreter itself is working with your unnamed SDK... that's a question that only you or the SDK vendor can answer.